# .stop() doesn't work with hover selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#deals ul li ul").hover(function(){
     $(this).stop().find(".trans").fadeIn("fast");
     $(this).stop().find(".text").fadeIn("fast");
     return false;
  },function(){
    $(this).find(".trans").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).find(".text").fadeOut("fast");
  });
  return false;
});
```

When you hover a few times quickly it will load those actions per second and stop() should make it stop but it doesn't work here, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.stop()` needs to be on the element that is potentially animated.

Your `ul` is not receiving the animation, so it doesn't do any good to `.stop()` it. It's the `.trans` and `.text` elements that are animated.

```
$(function(){
  $("#deals ul li ul").hover(function(){
     $(this).find(".trans").stop().fadeIn("fast");
     $(this).find(".text").stop().fadeIn("fast");
     return false;
  },function(){
    $(this).find(".trans").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).find(".text").fadeOut("fast");
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: True, but it has a problem with fadeIn effect. The problem is when you hover quickly and hover again the fadeIn effect will refuse to be shown fully, it will always stop midstream...

Comment: Use `.fadeTo("fast",1)` and `.fadeTo("fast",0)` instead.

Comment: Thanks but this is a better way $(this).stop(true, true);

Comment: It's neither better nor worse because it isn't equivalent to the code in your question. That will cause the animation to jump to the end of the current animation before it starts the next. If that's what you want, then sure, do that.